# replace a specific word in hundreds of files

Tags: search, find-and-replace

I have a folder tree structure with hundreds of java files distributed in various sub folders
I want to replace a word `Foo` with `FooBar` in each and every file
Individual instances of `Foo` should change to `FooBar` and `Foo.functionName()` should change to `FooBar.functionName()`
But something such as `myFooVar` should not be changed
What is the easiest way to do this in Windows XP? ( I have grep from GnuWin32 installed, if it can be used in anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a code refactoring task of a sizeable Java project. I generally recommend to use an Integrated Development Environment in that case.

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is pretty nice and can perform refactoring like renaming identifiers (even in comments and documentation). For specific help and tutorials on that topic hit the [official help pages](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm) or [look for more](https://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse+refactor+rename) [extensive resources](http://www.wikihow.com/Rename-Variables-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) on the net.

Comment: the reason I was asking this is because I am new to Eclipse and I am not sure how to do it. How do I replace this word in all the files of the java project using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure that you have a version control system or any other kind of backup.
It may be very hard to revert bulk replaces.

1. Install Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download
2. Open it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
3. Fill the form with your options.

[image: Notepad++ find and replace in files]

You can do much more complex operations, even multiline, with a power of regular expressions.